# Prove that $G$ is a connected graph.

Tags: graph-theory

**Problem:** Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ with vertex degrees $d_1\leq d_2\leq d_3...\leq d_n.$ Prove that if $d_k\geq k$ for all $k\leq n-d_n-1$, then $G$ is a connected graph.

**My Attempt:**  We prove this by contradiction. Suppose that the graph $G$ is disconnected. Then this means that the graph has at least two connected components. Clearly one of these components has $d_n+1$ vertices. This leaves $n-1-d_n$  vertices. How do I continue after this, please help!

Comment: It is easy to see that one of the components has *at least* $d_n+1$ vertices *provided that all loops are greater than $2$ in length* (but I still strongly recommend giving an off-hand comment as to why). However, I see no reason it can't be more than $d_n + 1$, thus leaving the other component with less than $n - 1 - d_n$ vertices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're nearly there.  One of the vertices is connected to $d_n$ other vertices, showing that there is a connected component $H$ of at least $d_n+1$ vertices.  If $G$ is not connected, there are $r\le n-d_n-1$ vertices not connected to $H$.  But at least one of these additional vertices has at least $r$ neighbors.  (Why?)  This is a contradiction.